# Unable to exit game whilst in menu states

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, exit

I am attempting to add exit functionality to let a player exit my game at various stages. I currently have it setup so that they can exit by pressing the escape button whilst in game. But am unable to add this same functionality within the Games main menu or game over menu.

Here is my code simplified:

```
// Game State Improvment
        // An enumeration for the different states in the game
        public enum GameState
        {
            GameMenu = 0,
            GamePlay = 1,
            GameOver = 2
        }
        // A variable to hold the current state
        GameState currentGameState;

/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            switch (currentGameState)
            {

                case GameState.GameMenu:
                    // commented in order to start the game without a menu
                    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Start == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                    {
                        levelIndex = 0;
                        LoadNextLevel();
                        level.Player.PlayerLives = 3;
                        currentGameState = GameState.GamePlay;

                    }
                    break;

                case GameState.GameOver:
                    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                    {

                        levelIndex = 0;
                        LoadNextLevel();
                        level.Player.PlayerLives = 3;
                        currentGameState = GameState.GamePlay;
                    }
                    //Add your game over update code here...
                    break;

                case GameState.GamePlay:
                    // Handle polling for our input and handling high-level input
                    HandleInput();

                    // update our level, passing down the GameTime along with all of our input states
                    level.Update(gameTime, keyboardState, gamePadState, touchState,
                                 accelerometerState, Window.CurrentOrientation);
                    break;
            }

            // If the ESC key is pressed, skip the rest of the update.
            if (exitKeyPressed() == false)
            {
                base.Update(gameTime);

            }

        }

        bool exitKeyPressed()
        {
            // Check to see whether ESC was pressed on the keyboard or BACK was pressed on the controller.
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) || gamePadState.Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Exit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
           // Game State Improvment
            switch (currentGameState)
            {
                case GameState.GameMenu:
                    //// Start drawing
                    spriteBatch.Begin();

                    spriteBatch.Draw(mainBackGround, Vector2.Zero, Color.Green);

                    //Stop drawing
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;

                case GameState.GameOver:
                    //// Start drawing
                    spriteBatch.Begin();

                    //graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(gameOverBackGround, Vector2.Zero, Color.Green);

                    //// Stop drawing
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;

                case GameState.GamePlay:
                    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                    spriteBatch.Begin();
                    level.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
                    DrawHud();
                    spriteBatch.End();
                    break;
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

How can I make it possible for the player to exit the game when in the GameOver and GameMenu gamestates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `HandleInput` in the other two cases.

Move that to just before the switch statement.